# Combination of $(document).ready and $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {...})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm using `JQuery UI` components in a `view` of `AngularJS`/`JQuery` application.

I need something like this (does not work) in my `JavaScript` code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var elem = $('div[ng-view]')[0];
    var $scope = angular.element(elem).scope();

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

          // multiple JQuery statements
          // to support JQuery-UI componenets

    });
});
```

This code is included as `<script>` into **index.html** that has `<div class="container" ng-view>` element.

My thinking was that we need a two-step process:

- First `JQuery` reacts on document-ready HTML event and attaches a listener to Angular's `$viewContenLoaded` using `$scope` retrieved using `[ng-view]` element.
- Then each time a view is loaded my `JQuery` code will be executed and `JQuery UI` components get activated and wired.

Apparently my logic is flawed somewhere. Please point me in the right direction.

**ADDITIONAL INFO** (*posted 03/31/14*):

The rest of my code (controllers, service, routing) is written in `TypeScript`.

Comment: Or you could put your jQuery code within angular directives. The jQuery UI initialization code can be placed within the directive's link function.

Comment: Yes, I will be looking into Directives but need something to work meanwhile.  I'm just starting with JavaScript and its tooling, so I have not covered most of the ground yet.

Comment: If you're going to take a gradual approach, then you could add the jQuery initialization code inside your controller, but know that you will want to move it into directive(s) to allow you to unit test your controller. When unit tests are run, you don't want anything directly tied to the DOM within your controllers.

Comment: My controller code is written in `TypeScript`. I was not able to find `JQuery UI's` official (i.e. guaranteed to work) definitions.

Comment: I have not used TypeScript so I won't be of any help there, I'd suggest posting a new question about that.

Answer (score 1):

That element needs to be compiled in order to bind angulars scope to that element. You could try something like:

```
var scope = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope').$new();
var compile = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$compile');
compile(elem)(scope);
scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

// Your code

});
```

Though I would suggest putting your code in a directive. The code I shown above is nothing more than a hack and dangerous since now you have global access to your services.

Comment: Do I keep my `var elem = $('div[ng-view]')[0];`? If not, where `elem` would come from?

Comment: elem, could be a string expresion of the html or a jquery/ jqlite element itself.

Comment: It should work like that. Personally I haven't tested the code that I gave you, but from the documentation and everything, I thought it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me.  I guess I would have to bite the bullet and learn directives.